# Sample Prestashop module does not appear for installation

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

This example is from [Prestashop Dev Docs](https://developers.prestashop.com/module/05-CreatingAPrestaShop17Module/02-CreatingAFirstModule.html)

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Helloworld extends Module {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'helloworld';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
        $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))
            $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');

        //$this->install();
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

        if (!parent::install() ||
            !$this->registerHook('displayLeftColumn') ||
            !$this->registerHook('header') ||
            !Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'my friend')
        )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall() ||
            !Configuration::deleteByName('MYMODULE_NAME')
        )
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

It appears only if I force uncomment $this->install(); inside constructor.
When I debuged it, I found that the action below removes it from page:

```
if ($module->database->get('installed') == 1
        && $module->database->get('active') == 1
        && !$filter->hasStatus(AddonListFilterStatus::DISABLED)
        && $filter->hasStatus(AddonListFilterStatus::ENABLED)) 
    {
        unset($modules[$key]);
        continue;
    }
```

helloworld.php and logo.png are inside /modules/helloworld

So the question is quite simple - how to install it through admin panel (/admin-dev/index.php/module/manage) after copying the contents?

I also tried to zip it and upload, but the error always occurs

> UndefinedMethodException
>   HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
>   Attempted to call an undefined method named "validateValue" of class "Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator".

Comment: You shouldn't have $this->install() in the __construct(). Why do you need it?

Comment: That was only way to install it, and then comment out again. Another solutions was to comment the if above.

Comment: The if above is inside file src/Core/Addon/Module/ModuleRepository.php

Comment: I also noticed that if I comment that if checking, I am able to install Contact form module that is not installed by default in Prestashop.

Comment: I have created folder `/modules/helloworld` and file `helloworld.php`, with exactly the same code that you pasted, and it appears in module list and can be installed. PS 1.7.2.2

Comment: The same happens even with generated module https://validator.prestashop.com/generator# I tried on Ubuntu and macOS, which env do you use?